# How to install farsi language in gnome centos

Tags: centos, gnome, keyboard-layout

I dont find `Farsi` or `persian` language in list of languages for add to keyboard layout.

How to add `farsi` or install it?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/persian-language-on-centos-844898/ ?

Comment: i dont find control center

Answer (score 0):

if you have gnome, 
click on 
Applications menu > Settings > Keyboard
go to Layout
uncheck 
use system defaults 
click on 
+ add 
from keyboard layout and find persian and add 
Persian (with Persian keypad)

if you have problem in fonts, try
yum install xorg-x11-fonts-type1

Answer (score 0):

and if you have KDE you can find it in 
keyboard -System Settings -> layout (tab) -> and add (+) pre (with Persian keypad)
;)

Comment: You are repeating the other answer